# How can I prevent koma-script from changing the font?

Tags: koma-script, bold, small-caps

The following code doesn't use KOMA-script ans is able to generate title with small caps:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

text \textsc{small caps text}

\section{title \textsc{small caps title}}

\end{document}
```

However, if I change the `documentclass` to `scrreport` to use KOMA-script, the title is no longer in small caps.

I took a look to the PDF properties and it looks like the fonts sfbx1728, and sfcx1728 were replaced by sfsx1728. How do I undo that ?

Comment: Because the default sans serif doesn't provide with small caps. If you want all the sections to be in `\rmfamily` adding `\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}` in the preamble should do.

Comment: Or, if this is a special, one-use case, you could do `\textrm{\textsc{small caps title}}`.  Probably look pretty terrible, however....

Comment: Duh. I tried the `\rmfamily` solution earlier, but with a `\setkomafont` and it didn't do what I expected. It works perfectly with `\addtokomafont`, what's the differences between the two ?

Comment: With `\setkomafont` you set that “font” to be exactly what you use there, e.g., if you use `\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}` you loose all the sizes (`\large`), series (`\bfseries`), shape (`\upshape`) etc. With `\addtokomafont` (which is the one I usually use), you only override those parameters you write, so `\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}` will keep every series/shape but only override the family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default sans serif doesn't provide with small caps. If you want all the sections to be in `\rmfamily` adding `\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}` in the preamble should do. Of course you could also load another font which does provide with sans serif small caps.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

text \textsc{small caps text}

\section{title \textsc{small caps title}}

\end{document}
```