# Using a single small caps word in header/ section title with KOMA-script

Tags: fonts, koma-script, small-caps

I am writing a paper and would like to emphasize all software names using small caps.
To easily manage this, I create a macro to set text to small caps, which works fine most of the time.

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\tool}[1]{\textsc{#1}\xspace}

% ...

\section{Analysis of \tool{software}}  % doesn't work

This is my \tool{software}.  % works perfectly
```

However, since my document type is **scrartcl** my macro doesn't work in titles and headers.
This is most likely the case, because the font used for titles does not have small caps.

Is there a way to create a macro like the one above that works in headers?
There are [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186221/how-can-i-prevent-koma-script-from-changing-the-font) [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83001/sections-heading-in-small-caps) which completely change the header font to a small caps font,
but I would like to keep the 'normal' header font.

Comment: Just my two cents: I would not recommend to mix a sans serif font with the sans serif small caps of another font. If you want sans serif small caps use a sans serif family that provides small caps.

Comment: I agree that this most certainly is not best practice. I posted this more to show that it is possible. I will edit my answer to point this out more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to solve this without completely changing the header font, as suggested in the other questions,
it is possible to change the font to a similar sans serif font that supports small caps.
I tried the fonts from [this list](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_typefaces) and modified the code proposed by @egreg in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193411/87700).
I found two fonts that are similar enough for me to tolerate and created a macro that unsets the active font family.
It then sets the text given as parameter one in small caps and reinstates the default KOMA-script header font (`\sffamily`) after that.

```
\makeatletter
\let\scshape\relax % to avoid a warning
\DeclareRobustCommand\scshapehead{%
  \not@math@alphabet\scshape\relax
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{\familydefault}=\z@
   \fontfamily{phv}% sans, but a little blocky
%  \fontfamily{qhv}% sans, but a little blocky
%  \fontfamily{qtm}% serifs, but looks ok
  \fi
  \fontshape\scdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\headtool}[1]{\rmfamily\scshapehead{#1}\sffamily\xspace}

% ...
\section{Analysis of \headtool{software}}  % works perfectly

This is my \tool{software}.  % works perfectly
```

Note that this defines a command `\scshapehead`, since using the name `\scshape` here would overwrite the normal behaviour of `\scshape` and the font would be changed for all uses of `\scshape / \textsc`.